# Problem with miktex-20.6.29-x64 and BibteX

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

Two days ago I installed the new MikteX on my Ubuntu. Since then I can't compile the text, with which I had no problem before that. I tested the file with the older version of Miktex on my laptop and it worked. The error with the new version is the following:

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 20.6.29) The top-level auxiliary file: Test.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file Test.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Test.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Test.aux (There were 3 error messages)
>
> Process exited with error(s)

The error appears only when I use BibteX. I'm not sure if it's relevant, but here is my code:

```
\documentclass[
10pt,
parskip=half,
listof=totoc,
bibliography=totoc,
index=totoc,
]{scrbook}
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}

\usepackage[includehead=false, includefoot=false, paperheight=240mm, paperwidth=170mm, 
twoside=true, left=25mm, right=20mm, top=35mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[LAE,LFE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,greek,farsi,main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[authordate-trad,backend=biber,natbib]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\vspace*{1cm}
{\bfseries \Large Titlepage\par}
\end{titlepage}

\chapter{Abstrakt}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter
\chapter{Something1}
Somethings in chapter 1. \citep{Pr20}
\chapter{Something2}
Somethings in chapter 2.

\backmatter

\printbibliography[]

\end{document}
```

I appreciate any help and clues.

Comment: you are using biblatex-chicago with backend=biber, so you should use biber and not bibtex.

Comment: You may have to re-configure your editor to run Biber for you, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for details. Currently you are running BibTeX, but your document needs Biber (as Ulrike already pointed out).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer and moewe : Thank you for the hints! It worked.